# Добавление и удаление классов в js

Tags: javascript

Как добавить класс блоку и через некоторое время удалить его?

```
if(tabImg.classList.contains('fadeInLeft')){
        tabImg.setTimeout(tabImg.classList.remove('fadeInLeft'), 1000)
    }
    else {
        tabImg.classList.add('fadeInLeft')
    }
```

В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Ваша ошибка в том, что вы не прочитали, как пользоваться `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(tabImg.classList.contains('fadeInLeft')){
    setTimeout(function(){tabImg.classList.remove('fadeInLeft');}, 1000)
}
else {
    tabImg.classList.add('fadeInLeft')
}
```